# Filtering rows based on a search word if found in any row irrespective of columns

Tags: excel, vba, rowfilter

Hi I have a huge data in an excel, I wanted to filter the rows based on a search word if found in any of the three columns that are not in series.

Comment: Could you please elaborate a bit more? What have you tried so far? How does a sample data set look like?

Comment: The easiest way to do this will be to use the macro recorder, just start her recording, set your filters to what you wish, then open the macro in VBA editor.

Comment: I have 5 columns with first name, last name, middle name, city, state, I wanted to filter row data (show the entire row even if the one columns has a value and rest are blanks.) if the name "Andrew" is present in any 3 columns (first name, last name, middle name)